# How can I know the number of touch inputs in UWP

Tags: c#, input, uwp, touch, inkcanvas

I want to use some customized gesture functions that I made, so I need the number of touch inputs in InkCanvas.

Example of what I want to achieve:

- If the number of touch inputs is 1, then 1 touch input (So I could draw in InkCanvas)
- If the number of touch inputs is 2, then 2 touch input (So I could use the gesture function I made)

For now I only know how to get the total number of touch inputs using `pointerId` from this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerpoint).

Is there any other way? Or Is this impossible?